# Can't seem to disable Domain Partitions

Tags: trailhead, mydomain

so I've been attempting the Data Integration Specialist superbadge.  To be clear, I am not asking for directions to doing it.  In the third challenge, before the requirements, there is a yellow box stating,

"Before you proceed with the following section, make sure Use partitioned domains is unchecked in the My Domain setup page."

I went into the My Domain setup page, and could not find the checkbox.  I went into an older org I have, and found the checkbox where I expected it, but I still cannot find the checkbox for the org I created for this superbadge.  I looked into the documentation and found this,

"Qualifying new orgs get partitioned domains by default, and you can’t disable this feature in those orgs."
source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_partitioned_domains_enable.htm&type=5

Based on what I am reading, I cannot disable the function, and yet must to succeed with the trailhead superbadge.  Am I misreading the documentation, is this no longer a problem for this superbadge, and the yellow box needs to be removed, or is this a mistake in the superbadge itself, and one that needs to be fixed?

Comment: They do not want a partitioned domain because it changes the URLs. No partitioned domain  (disabled or not available) -> you're ok.